# C: Variable is uninitialized for linked list

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-value

I'm relatively new to C and I was creating a program that involves a linked-list. Here is a very abbreviated version of the code that's giving me trouble.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRLEN 100

struct Gene { 
    int num[4];
    struct Gene *next;
    };
typedef struct Gene item;

void build_list(item *current, item *head, FILE *in);

int main() {

    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;
    input = fopen("test.data", "r");
    output = fopen("test.out", "w+");

    item *curr;
    item *head; 
    head = NULL;
    int i;

    build_list(curr, head, input);
    curr = head;

    while(curr) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            fprintf(output, "%d\n", curr->num[i]);
        curr = curr->next;
        }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    free(curr);
}

void build_list(item *current, item *head, FILE *in) {

    char gene[STRLEN];
    char *tok;
    char gene_name[STRLEN];
    char *search = ",";
    int j;

    while (fgets(gene, sizeof(gene), in)) {

        current = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
        tok = strtok(gene, search);
        strcpy(gene_name, tok);
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            tok = strtok(NULL, search);
            current->num[j] = atoi(tok);
            }
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, it says variable `curr` is uninitialized, but even when I initialize it with `malloc` it throws a segmentation fault, or it prints out nothing at all. Why could this be?

Comment: You are aware that `build_list(curr, head, input)` passes an uninitialized value as the first parameter?

Comment: `curr` and `head` are passed by value....

Comment: Yes, how could I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sourav Ghosh have already explained what was wrong with your code and also suggested one way to solve it. Here is another way.

Instead of passing `current` and `head` as variables to be changed inside the function (i.e. as pointer-to-pointer), I would recommend that you use the function return value. In that way you don't have to use pointer-to-pointer.

Something like:

```
item* add_item(item* head)
{
    // Place a new item in front
    item* current = malloc(sizeof(item));
    current->next = head;
    return current;
}

item* build_list(item* head, FILE *in) {

    char gene[STRLEN];
    char *tok;
    char gene_name[STRLEN];
    char *search = ",";
    int j;

    while (fgets(gene, sizeof(gene), in))
    {
        // Get a new item
        head = add_item(head);

        // Fill data into the new item
        tok = strtok(gene, search);
        strcpy(gene_name, tok);
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            tok = strtok(NULL, search);
            head->num[j] = atoi(tok);
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

and from `main`call it like:

```
head = NULL;
head = build_list(head, input);
```

**Note:** For readability, I skipped all check for failing `malloc`. In real code you should always check whether `malloc` returned NULL.

Answer (score 2):

C uses pass by value for function argument passing. So, when you call `build_list(curr, head, input);`, `curr` and `head` themselves are passed by value and any changes made to those variables (corresponding parameters) will not reflect back to the caller.

So, in the caller,

```
 while(curr)
```

is accessing unitialized variable (meeory) which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you need to change `curr` and `head` themselves, you need to pass their address and make chages inside the funtion. Something like

```
 build_list(&curr, &head, input);
```

and

```
void build_list(item **current, item **head, FILE *in)
```

and

```
*current = malloc(sizeof(item));
```

may get the job done for you.

Comment: I did what you recommended, and it brought up a whole bunch of errors like 'member reference base type 'item *' (aka 'struct Gene *') is not a structure or union' and it still warns about the uninitialized variable. What went wrong?

Comment: @matnnar sorry, I did a mistake in the function call example, please check now.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still throwing 'member reference base type 'item **' (aka 'struct Gene **') is not a structure or union' as an error on lines 55 and 57. Could you explain to me how I could fix that?

Comment: @matnnar I don't know which is line 55 and 57. and did you change all the variables accordingly?

Comment: I...think so? 55 is `current->num[j] = atoi(tok);` and 57 is `current->next = head`.

Comment: @matnnar nope, you're not, remember, we changed the definition (type) of `current` and `head`? Please re-check the data types used.

Comment: @matnnar - I guess you are trying `*current->next = *head;` Change it to `(*current)->next = *head;` Pointer-to-pointer can be tricky and the code becomes hard to read. I avoid them when possible.